# Production build (from Play Store) only shows white screen

Tags: flutter

I am developing a TODO app for my son - all looks good when tested on emulator, however once I build and upload to Play Store (currently is Android only) - when downloaded from there it shows only white screen. No exceptions, does not crash either, just stays at a completely white screen without any Flutter controls visible.

I have tested also on a real device - when uploaded from the debug build it also works as it should. Also created completely new project and moved my coding there (my research showed there might be some issues with white splash screen, which is deprecated meanwhile) - this also did not improve the situation.

Not sure what the reason could be for such strange behavior, all ideas are most welcome.

I am using latest version of flutter and flutter doctor shows no issues either:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.795], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] Connected device (5 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Debug and build releases even use the same signing configuration (although when uploaded to the store it gets repackaged by Google):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
    }

    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Here are the dependencies I have:

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
convex_bottom_bar: ^3.0.0
flutter_slidable: ^2.0.0
backdrop: ^0.8.0
intl: ^0.17.0
linkify: ^4.1.0
flutter_linkify: ^5.0.2
http: ^0.13.4
path_provider: ^2.0.7
flutter_guid: ^0.2.0
collection: ^1.15.0
email_validator: ^2.0.1
change_app_package_name: ^1.0.0
google_sign_in: ^5.2.1
date_util: ^0.1.4
url_launcher: ^6.0.18
confetti: ^0.7.0
flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^2.0.5
flutter_styled_toast: ^2.0.0
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^20.1.50
flex_color_picker: ^2.3.1
awesome_notifications: ^0.6.21
flutter_isolate: ^2.0.2
flutter_foreground_task: ^3.7.3
```

In addition:

1. Going to the android project folder and executing
   .\gradlew build --warning-mode all
   is successful - no errors, no warnings.
2. executing
   flutter run --release --verbose
   with attached real device brings up the app as expected, no errors, no nothing.

This is the current link to the app in the Play Store, not much to be seen though except for a white screen, and the screenshots how it actually looks like in emulator:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magicwareapps.taskmanager

I am already going crazy here, so any ideas are very much appreciated!

Edit: here is the output when the app is starting, it seems no widgets are misplaces/misconfigured:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on ASUS Z01QD in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/OpenGLRenderer( 2479): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer( 2479): Swap behavior 1
D/        ( 2479): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa7562a80, tid 2671
E/EGL_adreno( 2479): CreateContext rcMajorVersion:3, minorVersion:0
D/EGL_adreno( 2479): eglCreateContext: 0xbc4858a0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/        ( 2479): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa769f7c0, tid 2603
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:52069/smfbXRY68NE=/ws
I/art     ( 2479): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 13821(1024KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 53% free, 2MB/5MB, paused 131us total 141.590ms
I/Choreographer( 2479): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/EGL_adreno( 2479): CreateContext rcMajorVersion:3, minorVersion:0
D/EGL_adreno( 2479): eglCreateContext: 0xa7505e00: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
E/EGL_adreno( 2479): CreateContext rcMajorVersion:3, minorVersion:0
D/EGL_adreno( 2479): eglCreateContext: 0xa7505e60: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/        ( 2479): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9a57fb00, tid 2695
W/MediaSessionCompat( 2479): Couldn't find a unique registered media button receiver in the given context.
I/flutter ( 2479): 17:02:54: All notification permissons allowed
I/flutter ( 2479): 17:02:55: All notification permissons allowed
E/EGL_adreno( 2479): CreateContext rcMajorVersion:3, minorVersion:0
D/EGL_adreno( 2479): eglCreateContext: 0xb9ba19c0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
E/EGL_adreno( 2479): CreateContext rcMajorVersion:3, minorVersion:0
D/EGL_adreno( 2479): eglCreateContext: 0xb9ba1a20: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/        ( 2479): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9a858b40, tid 2716
W/MediaSessionCompat( 2479): Couldn't find a unique registered media button receiver in the given context.
I/Choreographer( 2479): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/flutter ( 2479): 17:02:56: All notification permissons allowed
I/flutter ( 2479): 17:02:56: FOREGROUND TASK START CALLBACK
I/flutter ( 2479): 17:02:56: foreground service start
I/flutter ( 2479): 17:02:56: foreground service event received
```

Not sure what is this with the media receiver...going to look it up now.

Comment: Generally only "red" errors in vibration are considered. Checks if any alerts are displayed on this screen. https://alstraruss.medium.com/gray-screen-issues-in-flutter-dfb6903d3411

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
No warnings for misplaces/misconfigured widgets though... I will paste the output in the original question, too long for a reply.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I believe this issue is happening from the flutter_foreground_task package. I got the same white screen issue and error messages when I'm opening up the app from the notification just by running the sample code posted for this package. I have brought this issue up to the developer: https://github.com/Dev-hwang/flutter_foreground_task/issues/110

Comment: No, unfortunately the issue is not resolved, I ended up removing the flutter_foreground_task package completely. However, I am facing weird issues with all kind of background or foreground unattended invocations - like executing code in isolate, so not sure if the issue is in my setup or something changed in the platform... of flutter. Here is my thread regarding isolate issues, got some responses, but nothing helped so far. All issues are only in the production build, dev/debug works fine:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73514653/flutter-isolate-not-working-in-release-mode-on-android

Comment: @J0nathanLam Did you (or anyone else) solve this? I'm having the same issues trying to run a foreground service while listeneing for SMS messages.

Comment: Not me :/ 
After some struggle I removed the foreground service and settled for a very unreliable solution involving isolates.

Comment: Hey guys, It looks this issue has been resolved in the recent package updates.

Comment: Hey, thanks for letting us know, @J0nathanLam, appreciated.