# Flutter isolate not working in release mode on Android?

Tags: flutter, flutter-android, flutter-local-notification

I have an app, which uses flutter isolate to show local notifications. This seems to work perfectly in debug mode and even in release mode pushed via "flutter run --release --verbose" with attached real device. However, when released to Play Store, the app as such works, but the isolate is never spawned - no notifications, also no exceptions or crashes. Simply... nothing.

Any ides what could cause such a behavior? What could case a isolate not to run? Again - in debug mode same code works like a charm...

Answer (score 6):

Maybe while building your .aab the compiler shrink or obfuscate some resources it thinks they are not used.
I think you have a callback function running on a separate isolate. So you can try to add something like this:

```
    @pragma('vm:entry-point')
    myCallback() {...}
```

this forces the compiler to keep that function.
You can also try to add to android.buildTypes.release in app/build.gradle:

```
     shrinkResources false
     minifyEnabled false
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have those already. Plus, when I build I use  --no-tree-shake-icons (read somewhere that it might help) and --no-shrink (just in case in addition to the shringResources fase).

I am already getting crazy... and not so many posts in inet about this, so I guess i am missing something, but I absolutely cannot see what...

Edit: i haven't tried out the @pragma proposal! Thanks! Will try it out asap. Takes a couple of days to get approved by google though...

Comment: Edit2: actually I just found out there is faster way to test an app repackaged by Google:
https://play.google.com/console/u/0/internal-app-sharing
Doing this now.

Comment: Please, let me know any progress!

Comment: Not much of a progress so far :/
The internal app sharing seems not to work (any more?)... so waiting Google to approve my previous update to upload the @pragma suggestion. Will update the thread when I have progress.

Comment: The @MarcoB answer is correct, you need to add the pragma. The issue about firebase_messaging is present here: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9446 and the official pragma solution is here https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9446#issuecomment-1240554285. The problem is caused by an excessive tree-shaking of Flutter 3.3.0 (or higher) compiler, that's why in debug works. Compliments to MarcoB for having given the interpretation and the solution before the official one.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the links and the extra info, @Fabio.
Added the pragma, now waiting for the app to be released on Play Store. VERY long waiting times lately, waiting for 10 days so far.
Will update the topic when I can test the released app.

Comment: Today the app got finally released. Unfortunately not much changed - the isolate is still not called, with the pragma markup in place. Again - in emulator/debug everything works fine, no idea what breaks in release mode...

Comment: Were you able to find out a solution for this? @Kras

Comment: Nope, sorry  Ended up removing most of the notifications functionality back then... a bit sad that such a simple use case is not working. Though there might be light in the tunnel - I was just notified, that another issue in same domain might be resolved, checknit out in case it helps you further (pls notify if so). There I tried same thing with a package called Foreground Service, but there were some issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73191762/production-build-from-play-store-only-shows-white-screen